# Passing selected POST data with header redirect

Tags: php

Ok so, background: I have a form, the user inputs their data, i preview it to them, they check it, approve it and then i have a script which inserts it into the database pending approval.

The issue i wanted/want to get away from is, on the page displayed when the insert has been successful, if the visitor hit Refresh, the data would repost to the database, generating a new unique id. I discovered i can use

```
if($result){
header("Location: whateverpage.php");
```

To redirect them if there insertion is successful and get away from the refresh problem, however...

the next stage in my process was/is, i have them clicking a button to proceed to PayPal and pay, which when/if successful, returns their unique id generated on the original database insert script, through PayPal's IPN, and adds a 'true/false' int to the database so their record can be displayed.

So, what i want to know is, can i pass their unique id which i get from this on my insert page:

```
$bus_id=mysql_insert_id();
```

In the header redirect, so i can then post this information to PayPal to keep track of their order?

I hope that all makes sense!

Thanks
Dan

Comment: You can use params like this: `header("Location: whateverpage.php?id=$bus_id");` or save it in a session.

Comment: Hi, and thanks. So after $bus_id=mysql_insert_id(); can i add something like $_SESSION['$bus_id']; and then retrieve that on the next page?

Comment: Yes. [Basic usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

Comment: Sorry, newbie :) will give it a go and thanks for your help. Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't my answer but is thanks to @timaschew, i simply got around the problem by passing the id in a session variable. Basic stuff.

Thanks 
Dan